# How can I synchronize multiple fields for all of an Account's contacts?

Tags: apex, trigger, map

So we have two multi-picklist fields for contacts, Field1 and Field2. When the fields are updated, they should be updated for all that account's contacts, to have the same values (except where those values aren't available for a contact's record type, which is why it's a partial update). This worked for just Field1, but it doesn't always work for both Field1 and Field2. If both fields are updated at the same time, Field2 will only be populated where Field1 is. If Field1 is already populated and I try to update Field2, nothing happens. I'm using two different maps for each field, so overwriting shouldn't be a problem?

```
trigger syncContacts on Contact (after update) {
        map<id,string> conMap = new map<id,string>();
        map<id,string> contMap = new map<id,string>();
        set<id> accId = new set<Id>();
        for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
            Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
            if (c.Field1__c != old.Field1__c) {
             conMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Field1__c);
             }
            if (c.Field2__c != old.Field2__c) {
             contMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Field2__c);
             }
            accId.add(c.id);
        }
    
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        if( trigger.isupdate && checkRecursive.runOnce()){
            for(account a : [select id,(select id,AccountId,Field1__c,Field2__c from contacts where id not in : accId ) from account where (id in : conMap.keySet() or id in : contMap.keySet())]){
                for(contact c : a.contacts){
                if (conMap.containsKey(a.id)){
                    if(c.Field1__c!=null){ 
                    c.Field1__c=conMap.get(c.AccountId)+';'+string.valueof(c.Field1__c);
                    }
                    if(c.Field1__c==null){ 
                    c.Field1__c=conMap.get(c.AccountId);
                    }
                    }
                if (contMap.containsKey(a.id)){
                    if(c.Field2__c!=null){ 
                    c.Field2__c=contMap.get(c.AccountId)+';'+string.valueof(c.Field2__c);
                    }
                    if(c.Field2__c==null){ 
                    c.Field2__c=contMap.get(c.AccountId);
                    }
                    }
                    conlist.add(c);
                          
                          }
                          }
            }
                          
     Database.SaveResult[] result = Database.Update(conList, false);
    }
```

Edit: I've managed to "fix" the problem by creating a separate loop for Field2, updating a separate list, and using an additional database.saveresult to save that list. But this means I'm nearly duplicating 10 lines of code and doubling my loops/queries, which doesn't seem like a good idea. But it does work, so I guess the problem is on line 18: `id in : conMap.keySet() or id in : contMap.keySet()`. I still don't understand why though?

Comment: Maps have unique keys. Since you are adding both fields in same map in line  8 and 11, the previous value gets overriden that is why it will work only for one field.

Comment: @manjit5190, but aren't they different maps? conMap on line 8 and contMap on line 11.